# Dynamic table names in Entity Framework linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with ASP.Net MVC 5. When using a database context object, is there a way to use a variable for the table name, without having to manually write the query?

For example:

```
var tableName = "NameOfTable";

result = context.tableName.Find(...);
```

I know that particular code won't work, because tableName is not defined in context, but is there a way to achieve the desired effect?

There are some similar questions on this site, but they never really solved the problem and they were for earlier versions of entity framework, so I'm hoping that there is an answer now.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this but does creating partial classes for your entities and supporting a table name property solve your problem?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I can't think of a valid use case for this situation. Perhaps you can tell us what you are ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to optimize my code. I have several lines of similar code whose only difference is the name of the table. I want to be able to put that one line into a function and pass the name of the table in as a parameter.

Comment: So you are talking about generics rather than dynamic table names. For example, you can do `context.Set<Model>().Find(...)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using a switch to associate a particular `Type` to a table. You could also maintain use some sort of `Dictionary<string, Type>` object.

```
var tableName = "Table1";
// Get proper return type.
Type returnType;
switch(tableName) {
    case "Table1":
        returnType = typeof(Table1EntityType);
        break;
    case "Table2":
        returnType = typeof(Table2EntityType);
        break;
}
var query = context.Set(returnType);
// Filter against "query" variable below...
var result = query.Where(...);
```

-or-

```
var tableName = "Table1";
Dictionary<string, Type> tableTypeDict = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
{
    { "Table1", Table1Type },
    { "Table2", Table2Type }
}; 
var query = context.Set(tableTypeDict[tableName]);
// Filter against "query" variable below...
var result = query.Where(...);
```

EDIT: Modified for Entity Framework

EDIT2: Use `typeof` per @thepirat000 's suggestion

Comment: That's a LINQ-to-SQL context. I'm using entity framework, so I'm using dbContext. I can't figure out what the equivalent function for ExecuteQuery is.

Comment: You should do `returnType = typeof(TablexEntityType);`

Comment: does context.Set load the entire table to memory?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the helpful answers above, I also want to add this in case it helps someone else.

- If you are getting this error on the "Where" clause in Mark's answer:

  *'DbSet does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no acceptable extension method 'Where' accepting an argument of the type 'DbSet' could be found.*

  Installing the Nuget Package "**System.Linq.Dynamic.Core**" made the error disappear for us.
- If you need to access the **LINQ methods** and the **column names** from the table, you can code something like this:

  ```
  var tableName = "MyTableName"; 
  var tableClassNameSpace = "MyProject.Models.EntityModels";

  using (var dbContext = new MyEntities()) 
  {
       var tableClassName = $"{tableClassNameSpace}.{tableName}";
       var dynamicTableType = Type.GetType(tableClassName);      // Type
       var dynamicTable = dbContext.Set(dynamicTableType);      // DbSet

       var records = dynamicTable
             .AsQueryable()
             .ToDynamicList()
             .OrderBy(d => d.MyColumnName)
             .Select(d => new { d.MyColumnName })
             .ToList();

        // do stuff
  }
  ```

Comment: sgrContext is what?

Comment: @integrater it should be dbContext.  I've edited it.