# Get dynamic table name in MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I know there are a lot of solutions for such query but I'm not able to implement any of them.

I'm Passing table name to my function and want the EF to get the table result for the respective table value passed.

So this is my function (a `JsonResult`) in Controller:-

```
public JsonResult FetchTblData()
{
      string MyTableName= Request.Form["TblName"].ToString();

    using (EBContext db = new EBContext())
    {
        try
        {
            var EduTblList = db.(**MyTableName**).ToList(); // want to implement it here.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string innerMessage = (ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException.Message : "";
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = EduTblList, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
}
```

How can I do it without much code modification and simplest approach using EF or LINQ?
Please HELP

Comment: Simple and without modifications: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31033055/dynamic-table-names-in-entity-framework-linq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic table names in Entity Framework linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31033055/dynamic-table-names-in-entity-framework-linq)

Comment: `var EduTblList = db.Set(typeof(EBContext).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.Name == MyTableName).First()).ToList();`, at case of class name is same as table name.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code:

```
    public JsonResult FetchTblData()
    {
          string MyTableName= Request.Form["TblName"].ToString();

        using (EBContext db = new EBContext())
        {
            try
            {
             Type tableType;
               switch(MyTableName)
                {
                 case "MyTableName":
                    tableType= typeof(TableEntityName);
                   break;
                }
                var dbquery = context.Set(tableType);
                var EduTblList = result.ToList(); // want to implement it here.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string innerMessage = (ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException.Message : "";
            }

            return new JsonResult { Data = EduTblList, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't Understand this code:-   var dbquery = context.Set(tableType);
                var EduTblList = result.ToList(); // want to implement it here.